# Assigning shell variable with Grave Accent

Tags: shell, cyber-ark

I have created a script which will need to pass a variable to shell file

Below script when i ran in shell-> This are working as expected.
i will ran in my terminal ' sh /path/shell.sh '

```
echo "cyberark"
PasswordRetrived=0 # 0=No, 1=Yes
while [ ${PasswordRetrived} -eq 0 ] ; do
    OUT=`/opt/destinationpath -p  GetPassword -p ="password" -p environment="dev" some other stuff  2>&1`
    if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    #    some script..
    else
    #    some scripts
    fi

done
```

If i hard coded `OUT=/opt/destionation/ .. .. ..`
, this will work as expected. however i am making the script dynamic which i am assigning out as a variable.. so running on terminal will be something similar to ' sh/path/shell.sh "$VARIABLE" '

To keep the question simple, assume i have declared the variable within the script itself
 My updated shell.sh file will be as shown below

```
echo "start cyberark"
#VARIABLE
TEST='/opt/destinationpath -p GetPassword -p ="password" ....'
PasswordRetrived=0 # 0=No, 1=Yes
while [ ${PasswordRetrived} -eq 0 ] ; do
    OUT=`$TEST  2>&1`
    if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    #    some script..
    else
    #    some scripts
    fi

done
```

When i assign $TEST variable into OUT=$TEST 2>1, this will return error.

```
 Invalid characters in User Name. ["] is not allowed
```

i have tried using "$TEST" . Where did i go wrong on this as the logic seems to be correct.

**Update**
Instead of grave accent = ``
i found out i can use $() as command based on [What does Grave accent (`) symbol do in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42618946/what-does-grave-accent-symbol-do-in-terminal)

, question on this is that can we combine $() and variable together ? assuming

```
$OUT=$(${TEST}  2>&1)
```

Comment: You did not show the complete string which you assign to `TEST`, so we can't say much here.

Comment: BTW, you indeed should better use `$(....)`  instead of the old backquote-mechanism. While you can use it if you want, it is considered deprecated. You can still use it if you need to write shell scripts which should be portable accross POSIX shell **and** old Unix Bourne Shell. I don't think many people are still doing this nowadays. However, I don't see that this point would related to the code you posted.

Comment: It's a good idea to use `$(...)` syntax instead of back ticks, however it's not the cause of the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your are trying to evaluate a variable string (`$TEST`) as a regular command line. When the shell parses a command line, quote removal happens before variable expansion.

So the double quotes in `$TEST`, here: `-p ="password"` (and presumably for `-u ="user"`, which you haven't shown) are not removed, and passed to the program at `/opt/destinationpath`.

You can do:

```
TEST=$(/opt/destinationpath -p GetPassword -p ="password" ....)
```

To save the command *output* in `TEST` (instead of the command itself).

But this probably isn't what you want, as it won't recompute the command for every loop iteration.

If you need to run the command every loop, the simplest option is to do `OUT=$(/opt/destinationpath -p GetPassword ...)`.

If there's actually a need to get the command from a variable, you could perhaps do `OUT=$(eval "$TEST  2>&1")`, but `eval` comes with its own set of problems.

Instead, you can use a function, in place of `TEST`:

```
test_function () { /opt/destinationpath -p GetPassword -p ="password" ...; }
```

And in the loop:

```
OUT=$(test_function  2>&1)
```

The function will run every loop, and its output will be written to `OUT`.

In bash, functions can also be exported so that they are available in the environment of child shells.